# Custom Fonts in Android PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, custom-font

I tried to make custom fonts for my application. For that, I wrote this code in my html file:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: centurySchoolbook;
            src: url(/fonts/arial.ttf);
        }
       body {
           font-family: centurySchoolbook;
           font-size:30px;
       }
</style>
```

In my Html Body:

```
<body onload="init();">
<h>Custom Fonts</h>
    <div>This is for sample</div>

</body>
```

But, these styles are not applied to my html body..
Any help to solve this..??

Comment: You forgot '' around the URL. Does it work when you add those?

Comment: I think Klaasvaak means that you typed `src: url(/fonts/arial.ttf);
` (without the double quotes `"`) in your CSS code. Shouldn't it be `src: url("/fonts/arial.ttf");
` ? Could you test your code with this modification?

Comment: I tried like that also.. But o/p was same..

Comment: In fact, you may try to put your CSS code in a css file and not in HTML. I don't know why, but it seems that putting the CSS directly inside HTML makes it not to work :S...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I made it work after doing the following steps:

**-Put your CSS in a file, for example `my_css.css`:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "customfont";
    src: url("./fonts/arial.ttf") format("opentype");   
        /* Make sure you defined the correct path, which is related to
            the location of your file `my_css.css` */ 
    }
    body {
        font-family: "customfont";
        font-size:30px;
    }
```

**-Reference your CSS file `my_css.css` in your HTML:**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./path_to_your_css/my_css.css" />`

---

**Pay attention to the definition of your paths!**

For example, let's say you have the following directory structure:

- **www**

  - `your_html.html`
  - **css**

    - `my_css.css`
  - **fonts**

    - `arial.ttf`

Then, you would have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "customfont";
    src: url("../fonts/arial.ttf") format("opentype");   
        /* Make sure you defined the correct path, which is related to
            the location of your file `my_css.css` */ 
    }
    body {
        font-family: "customfont";
        font-size:30px;
    }
```

and:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/my_css.css" />`

---

**Note:** if you use jQuery Mobile, the solution may not work (jQuery Mobile will "interfere" with the css...).

So, you may try to impose your style by using the style attribute.

Eg:

```
<body>
    <h>Custom Fonts</h>
    <div style="font-family: 'customfont';">This is for sample</div>
</body>
```

One drawback is that it seems that the `style` cannot be applyied on `body`...

So, if you want to apply the font to the whole page, you may try something like this:

```
<body>

    <!-- ADD ADDITIONAL DIV WHICH WILL IMPOSE STYLE -->
    <div style="font-family: 'customfont';">

        <h>Custom Fonts</h>
        <div >This is for sample</div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Hope this will work for you too. Let me know about your results.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I tried the same with correct path..But, still no change.

Comment: oh... :( ... Are you using Android or iOS? Also, are you using libraries like jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Android, and included below tags: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
 src="js/phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: :O... oh I see... I'm not sure but I think jQuery Mobile is "interferring"... give me some secs...

Comment: Hey mate, do you want to use the font for a specific part of HTML, or do you want to use it everywhere in your page?

Comment: Could you try the example which is located in the end of my post? ( `<body>
    <h>Custom Fonts</h>
    <div style="font-family: 'customfont';">This is for sample</div>
</body>` )

Comment: Hey mate, if you want to use the font for the whole page, you may check the last part of my post (I re-edited it and made it work, including jQuery Mobile :) )

Comment: :(... ths is really strange... It may be different for Android maybe? I'll try on Android and let you know if I solve this problem :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why jQuery Mobile would "interfere" with custom CSS?  Or better yet, can you give an example of what you mean by "interference"?

Comment: @Littm i m using ur code in iOS, but it does not work. please help me out

Comment: @Immi: Hi mate! What is the format of your font file? Is it TTF? Also, did you tried your app on your device or only on the simulator?

Comment: @Littm spinwerad.ttf. i tried in simulator...Please help me out..I requirement is to display list of Font style. and select particular font style among those. and selected font style should be applied...

Comment: @Littm did you test it on the unicode test like arabic or pesian?
i have problem with arabic text and font not applied

Comment: @Littm Are you sure android supports font-face ?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem.  I put my css file in the `css` folder.  I put the ttf file in just the `www` folder and it didn't work properly, so I moved my ttf file into the `css` folder. Here is my code:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: CustomArial;
src: url('arial.ttf'); 
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    font-family: CustomArial;
}
```

If you are using jquery mobile, you have to override the font like:

```
.ui-bar-a, .ui-bar-a input, .ui-bar-a select, .ui-bar-a textarea, .ui-bar-a button {
    font-family: CustomArial !important;
}
```

You have to override the font-family in your css for whatever jquery mobile class having font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; to

```
font-family:CustomArial !important;
```

Now it will work. You can try like this, may be its useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Below works like charm for custom font with jQueryMobile and Phonegap:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Lato-Reg";
src: url("../resources/Fonts/Lato-Reg.ttf") format("opentype");   
    /* Make sure you defined the correct path, which is related to
        the location of your file `my_css.css` */ 
}

 body *{
margin: 0;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
-webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */

font-family: "Lato-Lig" !important;
font-weight: normal !important;

 }
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately, it didn't work. When I test the page using firefox or chrome everything is OK but in emulator it fails. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I tested it against the xcode on IOS. Are u trying it on Android ?

Comment: yes, I'm trying that in android, is there any way to do that?

Comment: I have not tried porting to android, u shld try asking this question.

Comment: And some explanation for why "it works like a charm"?

Answer (score 1):

here your can find the .ttf the google fonts : https://github.com/w0ng/googlefontdirectory

[image: this screenshot should help]

in your .css file

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 src: url('../font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similiar issue. The problem was with the path it was taking when the font was given through an external css file.
To resolve this, i declared the font URL inline in the body of index.html

```
<div>
      <style scoped>
        @font-face {
          font-family: Monotype Corsiva;
          src: url('fonts/Monotype_Corsiva.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
      </style>
</div>
```

It worked after declaring the font URL in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'centurySchoolbook';
        src: url('fonts/arial.ttf');
    }
   body {
       font-family: centurySchoolbook;
       font-size:30px;
   }
</style>
```

with quotes on the font-family and on the url worked for me, inside the html file and on Android.

It works on physical devices, but not on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The possible issues lies in default index.css in cordova. Check if the body element has style defined for "***text-transform:uppercase***".

Atleast that was the issue for me, after removing this from body element in default index.css if you are using in your application, may help you as well.

For me I was using gurmukhi/punjabi fonts, and after the above line removal from index.css it just worked like charm with below css definiitions only

Example :

```
.demo {
   font-family: anmol
}
@font-face {
   font-family: anmol;
   src: url(../fonts/anmol.ttf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied my ttf-fonts into the directory [app-name]/css and declared the font-families in the index.css there. See attached image:  [my edited index.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5vvQ.png) (Check the green marked areas in the attached picture). There i also changed the style "background-attachment:fixed;" "Helvetica, Arial, no-serif…" to "Open Sans, Open Sans Condensed, no-serif", – i also deleted the line "text-transform:uppercase". After that everything worked fine with my font "Open Sans".
Of course i also included my own stylesheet with declarations of the other styles and font-families of my project.

I am also using jQuery and jQueryMobile in that project. They use the same font (Open Sans), but i added additional fonts that work as well!

Happy coding!

Comment: Is my browser going bananas or you did post the same answer 3 times?!?

Comment: Sorry for that as i am new here … i just wanted to correct something in my sentences and thought it would update, but it posted copies…
SORRY :(

Comment: I tried to "delete recent posts" but that doesn't work.

Comment: Finally – i got it!
Must have been a cache problem as i used the back button for editing my first answer. Couldn't find edit-button anywhere before – but now it is here.