# custom font not working in phonegap

Tags: cordova, custom-font

I'm trying to use custom font in phone gap using-

```
@font-face {
font-family: "customfont";
src: url("./fonts/CFBacktoSchool-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");   
}
body {
    font-family: "customfont";
}
```

but it does not work for me.
What is the problem? Help me please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Fonts in Android PhoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454681/custom-fonts-in-android-phonegap)

Answer (score 2):

finally I overcome this issue on Persian And Arabic custom fonts,

Keep all the codes with `@fontface` as same as it is,
Download this package http://averta.net/labs/fa/?p=10

From extracted archive, add `bifon-1.1b.js` to your html and use this script

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    $('#txt1').text(FarsiStyle.convert('سلام عليكم').split('').reverse().join('').split(' ').reverse().join(' '));

}
```

which txt1 is a div or span.

Comment: salam mohandes, khoshhal misham ba ham connect bashim dar morede barnamenevisi Phonegap

Comment: @Salman since I don't know if it is legal to put my email address here or not, we can be connected via LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

The possible issues lies in default index.css in cordova. Check if the body element has style defined for "***text-transform:uppercase***".

Atleast that was the issue for me, after removing this from body element in default index.css if you are using in your application, may help you as well.

For me I was using gurmukhi/punjabi fonts, and after the above line removal from index.css it just worked like charm with below css definiitions only

Example :

```
.demo {
   font-family: anmol
}
@font-face {
   font-family: anmol;
   src: url(../fonts/anmol.ttf);
}
```