# Not able to use custom fonts in Phonegap

Tags: android, css, cordova, webfonts

After looking at various solutions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454681/custom-fonts-in-android-phonegap), I'm still not able to get Elusive Icons working in Phonegap.

It's working fine on my computer, but once I create the app using Adobe app builder, the web font icons are no longer showing.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

and my CSS looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Elusive-Icons';
  src: url('../res/fonts/elusive-icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../res/fonts/elusive-icons.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions to what I can do to fix this, I will greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found [this article](http://www.stuartarthurmorris.com/2014/10/phonegap-build-missing-fonts/).

The builder will not copy the files from the `res` folder, just the ones you link to in the config file.

So by moving the `/fonts` folder to my `css` folder, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest embedding the font directly into the CSS file. You can use a site like [Gift of speed Base 64 encoder](http://www.giftofspeed.com/base64-encoder/) or [Opinionated geek Base 64 encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/) to Base 64 encode your font. You will then need to modify your CSS file to use this embedded string instead of pointing to the separate font file.

**This can be done by changing:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Elusive-Icons';
  src: url('../res/fonts/elusive-icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../res/fonts/elusive-icons.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**To:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Elusive-Icons';
  src: url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,*Truetype Base 64 encoded string here*') format('truetype'),
       url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,*Opentype Base 64 encoded string here*') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Working JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/btxdpgvy/1/